# Private Nameserver not working properly with Godaddy domain registry

Tags: godaddy, private, nameserver

My domain name is http://www.markupchop.com

The domain was registered with GoDaddy. My hosting provider was youhosting.com. But as per their words i created the private nameserver as

```
NS1.MARKUPCHOP.COM  ->  31.170.163.241
NS2.MARKUPCHOP.COM  ->  31.220.23.1
NS3.MARKUPCHOP.COM  ->  173.192.183.247
NS4.MARKUPCHOP.COM  ->  31.170.164.249
```

under GoDaddy's hostname section.

Then the created nameserver was updated at youhosting.com. Even the website and the FTP is can't accessible, but the subdomains like http://cpanel.markupchop.com/ and the File Manager is working.

Please help me to troubleshoot it. Much thanks...

Comment: What IP address do you think you have published for `markupchop.com`?  Is it `93.188.160.57`?

Answer (score 0):

If subdomains work and the main domain doesn't, this is likely to be due to DNS propagation.

If your address has been cached, you will need to wait for your DNS TTL to expire before the address is cached again - your TTL is currently set at 14400 seconds (or 4 hours).

Querying the system default DNS server (in my case, Google's public servers):

```
cwatson@thor:~$ nslookup markupchop.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   markupchop.com
Address: 93.188.160.57
```

Querying your nameserver:

```
cwatson@thor:~$ nslookup markupchop.com 31.170.163.241
Server:     31.170.163.241
Address:    31.170.163.241#53

Name:   markupchop.com
Address: 93.188.160.57
```

Get your nameservers:

```
cwatson@thor:~$ dig ns markupchop.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> ns markupchop.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16615
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;markupchop.com.            IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
markupchop.com.     14399   IN  NS  ns3.markupchop.com.
markupchop.com.     14399   IN  NS  ns2.markupchop.com.
markupchop.com.     14399   IN  NS  ns4.markupchop.com.
markupchop.com.     14399   IN  NS  ns1.markupchop.com.

;; Query time: 35 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 25 17:08:55 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104
```